# From a Java method, how do I return an entire int converted from a string?

Tags: java, methods, converters

The purpose of this program is to type of a date like "9/7/1994" and return the numbers that are separated by the forward slashes.
So it should come out as:
9
7
1994

The problem is that once I enter the date it'll return only
9
7
1

I've thought about looping the getYear() method but I'm not how to go about that or if that's the right thing to do.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Testing 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    getDate();
    getMonth(args);
    getDay(args);
    getYear(args);
}


public static void getDate() 
{

    System.out.println("Please enter a date: ");
}


public static int getMonth(Object c) 
{
    char ch = getInputChar();

    int month;

    getInputChar();

    String temp = Character.toString(ch);

    month = Integer.parseInt(temp);

    System.out.println(month);

    return month;

}
public static int getDay(Object c) 
{
    char ch = getInputChar();

    int day;

    getInputChar();

    String temp = Character.toString(ch);

    day = Integer.parseInt(temp);

    System.out.println(day);

    return day;
}
public static int getYear(Object c) 
{

    char ch = getInputChar();

    int year;

    getInputChar();

    String temp = Character.toString(ch);

    year = Integer.parseInt(temp);

    System.out.println(year);

    return year;

}

static char getInputChar() 
{
    char c = '\0';
    try
    {
        c = (char) (System.in.read());
    }
    catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {}
    return c;
}


}
```

Comment: did you try stepping through your program in a debugger?

Comment: You are only reading one character, try reading the entire line and splitting using String.split("/")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only get one digit from year because you only read one digit. following is a modified version of getYear() which prints all 4 digits.

```
    public static void getYear(Object c){
    int year_digit=0;
    String temp;

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        char ch = getInputChar();
        temp = Character.toString(ch);
        year_digit = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        System.out.println(year_digit);
    }
    }
```

I have one suggestion on your algorithm: 
In getMonth and getDay, you call getInputChar twice to get one char and skip '/' behand it. you are assuming the month and day only have one digit. what about 10/10/1944?   A possible alternative algorithm is to read the whole string from input stream, and use [the input string].split('/') to get array of string for month, day and year.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need and it helped so much. You were right about the 2 digits months. Unfortunately, I cannot use arrays in this assignment. I'll be changing things soon.

Answer (score 3):

You can take advantage of Java's String regular expression abilities.  Try the following code to parse and extract the three integer dates from an input String `date`.

```
String date = "9/7/1994";
// the following pattern matches dates of the format DD/MM/YYYY
String pattern = "(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(date);

if (m.find()) {
    String day = m.group(0); // 9
    String month = m.group(1); // 7
    String year = m.group(2); // 1994
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Testing 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        getDate();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String date = sc.nextLine();
        String [] numbers = date.split("/");

        getMonth(numbers[0]);
        getDay(numbers[1]);
        getYear(numbers[2]);
    }

    ...
}
```

Will that help you get what you need?

Answer (score 0):

The entire program has a two-line (or 5 if you include input format checking) solution:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a date: ");
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = s.nextLine();
if (!input.matches("(1[012]|[1-9])/(3[01]|[12][0-9]|[1-9])/\\d{4}"))
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
System.out.println(input.replace("/", " "));
```

To produce the correct (String) output, it is not required that you parse to integers then convert back to String.

Comment: Good answer, but this solution won't check for the correct formatting of the input.

Comment: @tim neither does OP. nevertheless, I've added something plausible